# What other words can be used instead of "hideable"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm trying to describe the scenario whereby something can be "hidden". I can use "hideable" however I wonder if there's a more eloquent term than "hideable"?

Comment: This seems to be a question of computing terminology rather than a language question, since the *hideable objects* in question are apparently programming objects to be displayed or not displayed on screen.

Comment: Class-naming is explicitly off-topic. As a general rule, something which is descriptive is good: what is **wrong** with *hideable*?

Comment: I haven't been here in a while, so I forgot about the class-naming rule. Regarding your question, the word *hideable* seems esoteric (maybe it isn't), and for that reason I thought it might be a poorer choice than other, more vivid words (if they exist).

Comment: This question is explicitly on-topic. Question is not about computer programming but about synonym for a word in English.

Comment: @PetrGladkikh, I agree that this question should be reopened. The fact that this word may end up being used as a class name is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Why are StackExchange moderators so quick to close questions? That is the single thing I hate the most about this network. Just let people be already! Err on the side of assuming the best of people. Please...

Comment: If he didn't mention why he needs this word, probably it was some good answers here!

Answer (score 13):

I have recently had this very same dilemma. In the end I went with 'hidable'. It is extremely clear what is meant, and so is *better* than using a word like *removable* or the ugly *toHide*. It doesn't appear in every dictionary but according to *[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hidable)* it is a word; though without the 'e'. That's good enough for me.

Comment: Doing a quick google search for hideable and hidable, it looks hideable is more popular! Also according to wictionary, they are alternative: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hideable

Answer (score 1):

There is also ***concealable***. [Free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/concealable) has an entry for it as an adjective formed from the verb ***to conceal*** (synonym of ***hide***). [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/concealable) defines it as

> Able to be concealed.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hidable%2C%20hideable%2C%20concealable&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chidable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chideable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconcealable%3B%2Cc0) gives it preference over ***hidable*** and ***hideable***.